# How to use named imports (ES 6) in NodeJS 14.x?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I have code which I like to use inside nodejs (14.4) and the browser. For this code to work inside nodejs I need named imports like

```
import {Vector3} from "three;
```

ES 6 modules in general are working fine with the following changes:

package.json:

```
"type": "module",
```

An launching nodejs with `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` so I don't have to specify file extensions. But for named imports nodejs still prints out:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'three' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports.
```

There is a Stackoverflow post suggesting the usage of esm package loader. Unfortunately it has a bug making TypeScript "reflect-metadata" unusable (Issue: https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/809) So I can't use that.

TL;DR; How can I enable named ES 6 modules in nodeJs 14.4 without ESM package loader? type: module and launch arg are already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the perfect answer but I solved my problem by switching the code base to Type Script (TS):

- For browser, I can configure ts to use es 6 modules
- For node, I can configure ts to use node modules

--> Everybody is happy